# Do you have to be an expert to post an answer?

Tags: discussion, answers

The question is pretty straightforward so I expect a yes or no answer. In order to post an answer on a question from Stack Overflow do you need to be an expert in the domain of the question? Is it assumed by the community that all the answers are given by domain experts?

I was not sure about this but I gave an answer and a user in comments assumed I am an expert, which I am not (especially in a very difficult domain) and since the user has much experience with SO (100k+ experience) I assumed he must know something that I do not know.

Comment: My guess is since you answered on a very difficult domain, he assumed you were an expert.

Comment: I have a feeling this belongs at AskCaptainObvious.

Comment: I'm a philosophical behaviourist by inclination. How can anyone tell you are an expert here, other than assessing the quality of your answers? If an answer has up votes, and no comments pointing out flaws, and has been around long enough to be criticized of it were wrong, what else can a reader do but assume it is correct?

Comment: Very few people on SO are "experts". Trivial questions get posted all day that can be answered by almost anybody. Even worse, there are so many of these that there are people who answer things they have no clue about, thinking it's one of those trivial questions. Rep says nothing. It is easy to rep-whore here.

Comment: No--in fact I once had an answer accepted over the answer of a guy who had actually created the framework that the question was asking about. Crazy :-)

Comment: Yes, you must be an expert. No, you don't. Whatever.

Comment: Arguably anyone who can give a good answer to a good question *is* an expert in some domain involving that question.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12474191/1110381) is my third highest voted answer on SO, and the question has a ton of views, which obviously means that it's helping people. I have never programmed in CUDA and don't know anything about it except for a basic overview of the technology from skimming wikipedia; I answered the question with 2 minutes of googling. So no, you don't have to be an expert, as long as you can write a useful answer.

Comment: No. You need to have the correct answer and the ability to communicate it. Example: somebody might ask a question about a framework you are not familiar with, but you might be able to immediately see the problem (it might not be ulitmately a framework question at all). In that case, you shouldn't feel constrained by not "being an expert"

Comment: In the real world, experts are considered to be people with a PhD in the field, or a Masters in the field and 5+ years of relevant experience. We could use more of those here, but you don't have to be an "expert" to post an answer.

Comment: I'm slightly disappointed that no one here has a full in-character answer guise of the (o.Q) esteemed tea-and-crumpets *Meta SO Expert with 18 years of question-answering experience and a PhD dissertation regarding the Proper Etiquette Answering Meta Questions as an MSO Member*.

Comment: Two observations:  1. What's an expert?  Bjarne Stroustrup says he is not an expert in C++ (he wrote it); he's spent too much time with the rest of the ISO committee.  2.  Experts make mistakes too, which is why a public answer is so valuable.  When Jon Skeet says something wrong in an answer about C#, *everybody* is going to point it out (with citations) - just so they can say "I corrected Jon Skeet!".

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I would read [this article](http://blog.codinghorror.com/how-to-write-without-writing/) by Jeff Atwood. Based on this, I'd say:

1. Whether you are an expert or not isn't the primary concern - the primary concern on this site is the ability to communicate. (We've all known experts who are knowledgable in a field but unable to communicate.)
2. To some degree, answering questions on this site can be as much a learning process as it is a test of your current skills, both technically and in terms of communication.

Comment: I believe that site creators know better why they created it.

Comment: Sometimes when I'm idle, I come here just to practice - The best way to learn is to overcome problems. That's why I love this site.

Answer (score 55):

You should be confident that you know the answer to that question, and that you understand it thoroughly enough to explain it effectively to someone else.

How much you know about other aspects of the domain or other domains not relevant to the question at hand is irrelevant.  If you only know enough about a topic to answer one single SO question about it (well) then you can still answer that one question.

If someone asks related questions or asks for tangential information on the topic you're welcome to either provide the information if you feel comfortable doing so, but you certainly are not *expected* to do so.  If the question is important to the user consider suggesting that they ask a new SO question for their tangential/follow up question.

Comment: Personally, I find it a challenge to read questions outside my comfort zone and trying to come up with an answer. This has led me to read primers on various programming languages and related topics. You never know what may stand out to you as a possible answer, and (hopefully) what will stick.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that, sometimes the `Confidence` leads to arrogance and due to which there was argumentative fight over comments. I have observed that in many answers (mostly with people over 100K+ rep) which even includes few answers posted by yourself. [Just a observation, nothing personal].

Comment: @Jongware yes, and in those cases this guideline is even more important. There's researching an answer you knew little about before, and then there's "trying to come up with an answer" in the sense of posting random untested guesses, which is different. (Not referring to the OP, or you, here! Or you, the reader.)

Comment: @Rahul This does not just apply to high-rep users. I've seen some low-rep users post poor answers and have the attitude that "the question is wrong and they are right".

Comment: @simonzack, that's true and it's a  wrong attitude.

Comment: @Jongware Sure, but you still shouldn't actually post an answer until/unless you are confident that you have arrived at a correct solution.  Whether you were confident in the topic when you read the question isn't important, but knowing that you know the answer when you actually post it is.

Answer (score 22):

I'm uncomfortable with the term "Expert".  It's a label that almost never belongs on folks without **very** tightly defined parameters.  And even then, more often than not it just leads people away from what should be the *true* goal: To keep on learning.

The bottom line as to whether or not you should offer an answer to a question is whether or not *you* believe you have an answer to the question that could help.  Nothing else really matters.

If you're in error, you can always clarify later.

Comment: Aye, expert is a pretty meaningless term. All it really means is that you've a better idea of how much you don't know.

Comment: An expert can even draw red lines in transparent ink - and more: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BKorP55Aqvg

Answer (score 10):

A person who posts an answer should know the answer or something relevant to the question that may help in attaining the answer. At the end of the day, if an answer is substantiated by examples, references and context, it need not be be coming from an expert. The end goal is getting the answer.

Also, problem solving skills is not a sole function of knowledge. It needs some intuition and creativity also. One should *learn* from an expert for a solid foundation, but *problem solving* can be done by anyone with the right tools and frame of mind.

Answer (score 7):

I found the comment you are referring to, and I think it was borderline rude, but it wasn't addressed to you -- you were at that point just a bystander.

RH wanted clarification -- either just to be clear or because he thought your answer was wrong/incomplete.

The "expert" comment was in the context of someone questioning his right to ask you for that clarification instead of doing his own research.

While you don't need to be an expert in order to answer a question, I would hope that in most cases someone that answers a question would understand the domain enough to be able to provide extra details -- not that they would, but that they COULD.

It is rare that a non-trivial question can be adequately answered without knowledge of the domain that extends at least a bit further than the question.  This was not a non-trivial question.

And that is how I would take the "expert" reference -- he was saying that you feel comfortable answering the question, asking you for clarification and/or supporting details isn't an abandonment of the RTFM principle, by answering you have implicitly volunteered to be asked for such clarification and can reasonably both be expected to know the answer and open to providing it.  Again, not that you have to answer, but not unreasonable to ask..

Answer (score 4):

Say the answer was simply *'yes, you must be an expert to post answers'*, what difference would that make?

Would we realistically be able to pre-vet your answers to make sure you're REALLY the expert you claim to be? Would your existing answers become somehow fundamentally less valuable?

**No.**

Mastery and expertise are not clearly defined states. They are not boxes you can check off. They are strange, rough approximations of how one's level of skill is perceived.  If you've been around here for awhile, you'll know one of the central tennets of this site is 'assess the post, not the poster'. We aim to steer clear of judgement calls about the individuals behind the posts because that's not what we're here to do. We're here to solve each other's programming problems.

**Did my answer solve the OP's problem? Will my answer help the next person who has the same problem, and lands on this post?** Those are the only two things you need to ask yourself.

Answer (score 3):

You need to be able to [draw 7 red lines, all strictly perpendicular, two with green ink, and two transparent](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BKorP55Aqvg), on a 2D plane, to be considered an expert. Maybe even inflate a baloon in shape of a kitten (watch the video).

On a serious note, you don't have to be an expert to post an answer on Stack Overflow. However, people with 100K+ reputation tend to score higher, because their answers are usually of higher quality. This includes more professional wording, no repetition, straight to the point, and more technical details. Same applies for people with different professional experience. You do more of the same thing, you start doing it better, and with ease.

My definition of expert is being a person who knows multiple ways of solving the problem, and also how to move along, as requirements are changed/clarified. They can propose the best solution, having in scope such factors as money and time spent. Many businesses are looking for such people, even though it costs them a fortune.

People who ask questions on Stack Overflow are usually not businesses and they often don't need or can understand such a complex answer. Most of the time it's some simple answer to work for their small needs. Based on my experience on Stack Overflow, your highest gain of reputation is from being the first one to answer such small questions. You don't need a lot of experience to answer in this case.

However, the quality of your English matters, so practice your communication skills, googling and fast typing - and welcome to the circle of Stack Overflow experts. :)

Answer (score 1):

Whatever **being** an expert means - it's not important here.

It's only relevant whether someone **behaves** like an expert.

If someone is an expert on a topic in some formal way, but has a bad day and gives bad answers, we will not even know he's an expert. And it will not help much if he tells us.

If someone is not an expert in a formal way, but an expert in terms of actual active knowledge on the topic, there will not be any difference to a formal experd, on bad and on good days.

What about someone who's not an expert, but knows how to answer a certain question?
The answer could be clearly not from an expert. But it can also be like a bad day- or a good day expert's answer.
Users will read it - some of them being experts - and vote, etc.
After a while, the votes and comments will tell whether it's an expert-like answer.

The actual difference in behaviour of an expert is not that he can give better answers, it's that he can **answer more** questions of a topic. But that has no effect on the answers, because they are used in isolation.

> Do you have to be an expert to answer?

No - its optimal if you behave like one when answering an individual answer, and it's acceptable if you just try - that's what voting is for: filtering the expert-level answers from lots of these.

Answer (score 0):

No.

Anyone can answer.  Bad answers get voted down.  Good answers get voted up.